# Jquery is not firing on Listview tr click event

Tags: jquery, listview

I was able to get this to work on a Gridview.
Ultimately I am trying to highlight a row when clicked.
For testing I am using an alert.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#WhiteRow tr').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("white");
  });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<asp:Panel ID="GridViewDrillIntoCell_Panel_All"
     runat="server"
     width="2000px" 
     height="380px"
>
<asp:ListView ID="GridViewDrillIntoCell_All" 
     runat="server" 
     ScrollBars="Vertical"
     ItemPlaceholderID= "myItemPlaceHolder" 
     UseAccessibleHeader="True"
     AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderCss2" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GV_Scorecard_Tab1_SelectedIndexChanged"
     OnRowDataBound="GridViewDrillIntoCell_All_RowDataBound"
> 
  <LayoutTemplate> 
    <div id="Listview">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
        <tr id="HeadingRow">
          <th id="hcol1" style="width:50px">Client</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="myItemPlaceHolder" runat="server">
          </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="WhiteRow">
      <td id="col1" class="ListViewStyle" style="width:50px"> 
        <%# Eval("LMClient")%>
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>      
</asp:ListView></asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your selector is incorrect.

`#WhiteRow tr` means select all the `tr` elements that are within an element with the id of `WhiteRow`.  So you are looking for rows within rows.

Comment: all the element within the tr are td - unless the place holder changes things. To simplify things, I am now trying just one row within the table. And I am still not able to get the click event to work.

Comment: I was able to get the one tr to work. Now to look at the original problem again...